# cart? does order and orderdetails needed?

Tags: php, mysql, database, html, phpmyadmin

I have made a cart system that will show only the products where customers add to purchase, i mean they would just calculate the quantity and the total price of all products.

I wanted to ask if it is necessary for me to add an order and orderdetails table in my database?i just dont want to include the cart in my ERD

**cart**
productNum
quantity

**order**
orderNum(PK)
orderdate
customerNum
cardNum

**orderdetails**
id(PK)
orderNum(FK)
productNum(FK)
numOrdered
quotedPrice
amount

can someone explaint to me briefly what im going to do, need some suggestions

PS. please dont correct me if i have mistakes on my idea, im still a student who wants to learn more from someone who is willing to teach me

Comment: A table is good if you want to save a customer's selections between visits and allow internal employees to see what a customer was considering. I believe most e-commerce sites use a cookie ($_COOKIE) to store the cart. The cookie can allow you to store the cart on the customer's PC and access it on future visits to the site. You can also use the $_SESSION variable to store the cart, but this variable goes away when the browser is closed.

Comment: I think that you database structure is not the best one for that kind of project

Comment: sorry not to mention, i dont realy need to upload it online , this is just a final project in my Web Development subj, by the way .. yes i have implemented a $_SESSION in customers table, its just that im still confused on how to make the structure out of everything

Comment: what can you suggest? im already brainstorming of strategies here .. im still trying to learn, though this is not one of the best project , but least i could explain the details and the implementation of the codes behind the project